# require('connect-mongo')(session) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to add the "connect-mongo" package in my NodeJS application, but it gives me this error I cannot debug.

I was watching Youtube Tutorial so I "copied" word-by-word what he has written, but when I restart the app, it crashes with this message:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)             
                                           ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

This is the code:

```
// Required libraries
const express = require('express')                                  // Express Package
const mongoose = require('mongoose')                                // MongoDB Package
const session = require('express-session')                          // Express Session Package
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)                // MongoStore
const app = express()                                               // Express Function
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "connect-mongo": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.18",
  }
```

Comment: You should read the documentation: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#readme  The new version of connect-mongo has some breaking changes.  You likely need to change that to `const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default(session)` but other things may also be different.

Comment: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/MIGRATION_V4.md